# Mp3 audio is not playing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

this is my swift class

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class MusicPlayer{
    static let shared  = MusicPlayer()
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    func startBackgroundMusic(backgroundMusicFileName: String) {
        if let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: backgroundMusicFileName, ofType: "mp3") {
            let backgroundMusic = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:backgroundMusic as URL)
                guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
                audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
                audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopBackgroundMusic() {
        guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

And, here is my code for the Controller class

```
func downloadUsingAlamofire() {
        let audioUrl =  URL(string:"https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3")
        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
        Alamofire.download(
            audioUrl!,
            method: .get,
            parameters: nil,
            encoding: URLEncoding.default,
            headers: nil,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                let imageURL = fetchPathinDirectory(filepath:audioUrl!.lastPathComponent)
                MusicPlayer.shared.startBackgroundMusic(backgroundMusicFileName: imageURL.path)
                
            })
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the place that you are expecting it to be once it is downloaded? As it looks like you are checking the bundle for the file and not the documents directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explain in comment ;

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
```

That means the file is downloaded in documents directory of your app. But when you read the file :

```
 if let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: backgroundMusicFileName, ofType: "mp3") {
    let backgroundMusic = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
```

You read for file in application bundle which is where your application and its ressources (storyboard, xib, …) are installed.
You must read the file from documents directory. Something like :

```
var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let downloadedFileUrl = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(backgroundMusicFileName)
```